# Laravel Redis delete all keys starting with a string

Tags: php, laravel, redis

This is Redis key like "product:1:list:somekey"
I want to remove all keys under list key

I used

```php
Redis::del('product:1');
```

function but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Redis::keys() method what you need

```
$keys = Redis::keys('product:1:list:*')
```

that will return array of keys for given pattern

after that you must prepend your global cache prefix

```
function addPrefix($keys)
{
    if (!count($keys)) return;

    $prefix = config("cache.prefix") . ":";

    return array_map(function ($item) use ($prefix) {
        return $prefix . $item;
    }, $keys);
}

$prefixed_keys = addPrefix($keys);
Redis::del($prefixed_keys)
```